# SQL Duplicating tables with groupBy

Tags: sql, duplicates, mariadb

I'm trying to compare income/outgoings using a simple query, but for some reason, I'm getting duplicated data. This is the query I'm running:

```
SELECT
    Event.Name as "Event", 
    Concat("£", round(sum(Ticket.Price),2)) as "Ticket Sales",
    sum(Invoice.NetTotal) as "Invoice Costs",
    Concat("£", round(sum(Ticket.Price),2) - round(sum(Invoice.NetTotal),2)) as "Total Loss"
FROM Ticket 
JOIN Event ON Ticket.EventID = Event.EventID
JOIN Invoice ON Event.EventID = Invoice.EventID
GROUP BY Event.EventID;
```

This is the result I'm getting

```
+--------------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+
| Event                    | Ticket Sales | Invoice Costs | Total Loss |
+--------------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+
| Victorious Festival 2018 | £47.94       |          1800 | £-1752.06  |
+--------------------------+--------------+---------------+------------+
```

Despite there only being 2 items in the Invoice table, totaling £600,
and 3 relevant items in the ticket table totaling £24.97

```
+-----------+--------+---------+---------------+-------------+----------+------+
| InvoiceNo | ItemID | EventID | HireStartDate | HireEndDate | NetTotal | VAT  |
+-----------+--------+---------+---------------+-------------+----------+------+
|         1 |      1 |       1 | 2018-05-05    | 2018-05-06  |      500 |   20 |
|         2 |      2 |       1 | 2018-05-05    | 2018-05-06  |      100 |   20 |
+-----------+--------+---------+---------------+-------------+----------+------+
    +----------+---------+-------+------------+------------+----------+
    | TicketNo | EventID | Price | ValidFrom  | ValidTo    | Class    |
    +----------+---------+-------+------------+------------+----------+
    |        1 |       1 |  7.99 | 2018-05-05 | 2018-05-22 | Standard |
    |        2 |       1 |  7.99 | 2018-05-05 | 2018-05-22 | Standard |
    |        3 |       2 |    10 | 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-28 | Standard |
    |        4 |       2 |    10 | 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-28 | Standard |
    |        5 |       2 |    10 | 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-28 | Standard |
    |        6 |       2 |    10 | 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-28 | Standard |
    |        7 |       2 |    10 | 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-28 | Standard |
    |        8 |       2 |    10 | 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-28 | Standard |
    |        9 |       1 |  7.99 | 2018-05-05 | 2018-05-22 | Standard |
    +----------+---------+-------+------------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two different *independent* dimensions.  The best solution is to aggregate *before* joining:

```
SELECT e.Name as "Event",
       Concat("£", round(sum(t.Price), 2)) as "Ticket Sales",
       sum(i.NetTotal) as "Invoice Costs",
       Concat("£", round(sum(t.Price), 2) - round(sum(i.NetTotal), 2)) as "Total Loss"
FROM Event e JOIN
     (SELECT t.EventId, SUM(Price) as Price
      FROM Ticket t
      GROUP BY t.EventId
     ) t
     ON t.EventID = e.EventID JOIN
     (SELECT i.EventId, SUM(i.NetTotal) as NetTotal
      FROM Invoice i
      GROUP BY i.EventId
     ) i
     ON e.EventID = i.EventID
GROUP BY e.EventID;
```

Two comments.  First, I don't really like aggregating on `EventId`, because it is not in the `SELECT` (preferring `EventName` instead).  Assuming that it is the primary key for `Events`, then this structure is fine -- the id uniquely identifies each row in events, so the name is well-defined.

Second, you might want to make the joins `left join`s, so you are including all events, even those that might be missing tickets or invoices.